# geometric program, function with sum of logs has unknown curvature

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimiztation problem from the paper "A Coded Compressed Sensing Scheme for Unsourced Multiple Access" with cvxpy. According to the paper the program is a geometric program, but the following constraint function has an unknown curvature: [image: constraint with unknown curvature]. Does someone have an idea how I can reformulate the constraint, so that it is log log concave and can be solved with cvxpy?

I tried to solve the optimization problem with `prob.solve(gp=True)`. I checked the curvature of the constraint with `print("log log curvature of constraint_M_B_f:", constraint_M_B_f.log_log_curvature)` and got log log curvature of constraint_M_B_f: UNKNOWN. The program finished with exit code 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [so] is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: DOI link to the paper, please

Comment: Hello everybody, I solved the problem. A change of variable p_j = e^x is sufficient to ensure that the optimization problem is DCP. I used the the solver in DCP mode instead of DGB mode.
The paper can be found here: https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1809.04745